# Toast inside getView() can't recognize the context

Tags: android

I have a custom list item that consists of 3 buttons. I want to show a toast when a button is clicked, but I'm a bit lost with contexts.
Here's my code:

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ButtonClass> {

    public ButtonAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ButtonClass> buttonList) {
        super(context, 0, buttonList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.button_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        ButtonClass currentButton = getItem(position);

        Button btnOne = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
        btnOne.setText(currentButton.getBtnOneString());

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // doesn't recognize the getApplicationContext() method ?!
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Msg to show up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        // the same thing for the other two buttons  ...

        return listItemView;
}
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: that's because ArrayAdapter doesn't have `getApplicationContext` method

Comment: its better to use context you are passing from your activity.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getContext()) instead of getApplicationContext().

getContext() method available in [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) class. while [getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) is available in your [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Use view context:

```
btnOne.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Msg to show up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
```